# How to mimic Heroku Kafka certificates?

Tags: heroku, apache-kafka, keytool

I'm trying to reproduce Heroku Kafka setup in a Docker environment.
Following Apache Kafka setup, I can create a cluster of 3 Kafka instance working great.

I follow the instructions on http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#security_ssl to enable SSL for that cluster, it seems to work ok with the generated JKS (cluster start without error).

Now I have problem to extract the client certificate, client certificate key, and kafka trusted certificate in PEM format as it appears in heroku platform (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/kafka-on-heroku#connecting-to-a-kafka-cluster for the description).

It seems a keytool /openssl usage question, hope you can help. Thank you.